# Determining if a time is GMT or BST in Java?

Tags: java, date

If I have a date supplied to a system written in Java, is there any way of telling if it is GMT or BST?

Comment: How might it be done?

Comment: Depends on if you're using a `Date`, a `Calendar` or something else. What are you using?

Comment: The date is simply received in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS as a string.

Comment: Then no. There's no information about time zone in that string.

Comment: As a string? In that case, no, you cannot find out what it is as it carries no meta-data. How about extending it to include a timezone 3 letter stamp?

Comment: oh my. a string. so much data.

Comment: "The date is simply received in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS as a string" - what does this have to do with Java then? In the string there is no information about timezone, so it doesn't matter where this string goes to - the information isn't going to suddenly appear out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For formatting, you should really use a DateFormat implementation (e.g. SimpleDateFormat). That will let you specify the time zone (and output format).

Ultimately, you need to post code so we know what a "date supplied to a system" looks like.

It can always be identified. (*EDIT: Unless you just got a string, like you did.*)

There's something like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) if you're interested in a TimeZone class.

Use those proper [DateFormat Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29). Answer your own questions, then ask the ones you *can't* answer. That's what SO is for.

The [Date class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is timezone dependent.

One google search prevents a duplicate like this.

Comment: Or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516213/java-util-date-is-using-timezone)

Comment: The answer that tried to be useful on a useless question...

Comment: This one or the one I posted? :)

Comment: I just meant my 4:30am internet scavenging... You're good :P

Comment: It's a valid answer and deserves at least an upvote ;) For a complete answer, references to `TimeZone` and `Calendar` could be added, along with a `SimpleDateFormat` example. If you're bored, expand on it ;) Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309264/java-calendar-timezone-issue) ?